# request.body vs request.params vs request.query

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, http

I have a client side JS file that has:

> agent = require('superagent'); request = agent.get(url);

Then I have something like

```
request.get(url) 
//or
request.post(url)
request.end( function( err, results ) {
        resultCallback( err, results, callback );
    } );
```

On the backend Node side I have 
`request.body` and `request.params` and some has `request.query`

What are the difference between the body, params and query?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`req.params` is route parameters, `req.body` is the actual body of the request, and `req.query` is any query parameters.

For example, if I declare this route:

```
router.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {});
```

`req.params` will contain `id`.

If I pass a body to this route:

```
{
  name: 'josh'
}
```

This will be in `req.body`.

If I pass some query parameters to `http://myserver.com/api/user?name="josh"`, `req.query` will be `{ name: 'josh' }`.

Check out the [Express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html).