# req.body is empty when apply middleware to a GET route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I write a router for authentication and a middleware to parse redirect parameter and save in session. But when parsing query parameters, both req.body and req.params are empty.

router.js

```
/* Route for Facebook login. This is the only login option for now. */

var router = require('express').Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var redirect = require('../middlewares/redirect');

/**
 * facebook oauth
 */
router.get('/facebook', redirect.parse(), passport.authenticate('facebook'));
```

redirect.js

```
/**
 * save the redirect parameter to session
 *
 * @param {Object} options options for the middleware
 */
module.exports.parse = function (options) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.params);
    if (req.body.redirect) {
      req.session.redirect = req.body.redirect;
      console.log(req.body.redirect);
      console.log(req.session.redirect);
      req.session.save();
    }
    next();
  };
};
```

When I call `/auth/facebook?redirect=/groups`, the output is:

```
{}
{}
```

The code is on Github https://github.com/guoyunhe/shrgrp

Comment: have you included body parser before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [request.body vs request.params vs request.query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175587/request-body-vs-request-params-vs-request-query)

Comment: @JakubPastuszuk I included body-parser in app.js, just like the default app created by express cli.

Comment: Can you show your app.js code?

Comment: @abdulbarik yes. it is on github https://github.com/guoyunhe/shrgrp/blob/master/app.js

Comment: @Mikey I think you are right! The req.query contains what I need. req.body is only for query parameters of POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, but not GET

Comment: Yeah `req.body` is always empty on a GET request. I believe `req.params` is only path parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are calling `GET` and expecting data from `req.body` which is not gonna work

With `GET` call you can get data in two ways:

> if it is `parameter` then you can get in `req.params`
>
> If it is `query string` then you can get in `req.query`